Read Block 1 from a CSN card(mifare classic card) using PC/SC
Im trying to read a Hex value from a CSN card.(using duali dragon desktop reader)
this is the data when I read it using NFC Tools app in my android phone.

I want to read the Addr.01 data in my console app.
this is the card's details.

and this is the data i want to read.

this is the code I have written so far.
using PCSC;

using (var context = new SCardContext())
{
    context.Establish(SCardScope.System);


    var readerNames = context.GetReaders();
    if (!readerNames.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No card readers found.");
        return;
    }

    // Connect to the first reader
    using (var reader = new SCardReader(context))
    {
        var sc = reader.Connect(readerNames[0], SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any);
        if (sc != SCardError.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to the reader.");
            return;
        }

        byte[] command = new byte[]
        {
                        0xFF, 
                        0xB0,
                        0x01,
                        0x00,
                        0xFF  
        };


        byte[] response = new byte[16];
        var readResult = reader.Transmit(command,ref response);

    }
}

but the response I get is just a byte array including 2 data. 106 and 5

how can I read the whole Block 1 (Addr.01) ?
any help is appreciated. thanks.

You are using a MIFARE Classic tag (and please change the title of your post to reflect this important data). These tags do not allow any reading (or writing) without prior successful authentication. A lot of (external / USB) card reader have a built-in command to do this for you. There are two steps required to run this on the external NFC reader:

step 1: load the key into readers memory and step 2: authenticate the requested sector (identify in which sector your block is located - in your case block 1 is in sector 0) with the key. In case of success you can read all of the blocks in the sector. Btw: better use NXP's TagInfo app as this app gives you a better overview of your tag and reads out the complete tag if a sector is secured with default key.

@MichaelFehr authentication keys are set to all 0x00. i can read using nft tools app. if there was authentication keys other than the default one, i wouldn't be able to read it. any code sample you can provide ?

As commented before, your reader will usually do this for you. You didn't name the reader name/type. See the API description of your reader and change your code to send the commands (1 authenticate, 2 read)  to the reader.

its duali dragon desktop reader

Perfect. The reader is supporting to stoe an authentication key in the reader and thr read/write commands are using this key to authenticate the sector with the stored key before reading a block. That makes it easy to read the block. Just follow the PCSC Protocol specification. Btw: asking for codes is off-topic here on SO

i load the key successfully . but it's never authenticated. no matter which key (A or B) it always return 6A17. i dont know why

Of course not, you are sending a command "0xB0h" for a "Mifare card". You need to send the command for a Mifare block that is "read Mifare Block" ("0x35h"). Btw: I asked you before: please edit your post  title to reflect you are question is about a MIFARE Classic tagm thanks.

Update: edit of post title is already done, sorry !
